# Flutter: (location plugin) build issue due to java sdk

Tags: java, flutter, gradle

I am using flutter location package ^4.1.1 and this is the error message I am getting.

[image: Error message]

My flutter doctor results show that I am using JDK 1.8..

[image: Flutter Doctor Results]

So my question is, do I need to configure the java source in my flutter project, in the build.gradle or some other place in order to make it point to my current version of Java? In my build gradle I did see a dependency implementation of kotlin pointing to jdk7. Tried changing that to jdk8 but didn't work.

```
dependencies {
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"}
```

I've done a ton of searches on google but couldn't find anyone in the same predicament as me which is why I finally gave up and had to make an account here to ask for help. Just a side note, I am using vscode for developing this project as part of a flutter course. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

[RESOLVED] Turns out the issue was not on my side but the developer's version of the package. He has released a patch fix to that package ^4.2.1. 3 days wasted trying to fix this issue on my end but all's well that ends well I guess. Hope this helps someone else facing the same issue.